# How to design function interfaces that can deal with varied number of arguments or having any combination of argument types?

Tags: c++

Occasionaly I find that I need a generic "pass through"-interface. For example for mix-in classes that forward their constructor arguments to the parent. Or for factory methods that forward their arguments to `new`:

```
template<typename C>
C * Create();

template<typename C, typename Arg0>
C * Create(Arg0 & a);

template<typename C, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
C * Create(Arg0 & a, Arg1 & arg1);

template<typename C, typename Arg0, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
C * Create(Arg0 & a, Arg1 & arg1, Arg2 & arg2);
```

When putting the idea into practice I find that it usually works.

However, there are a few problems:

- When passing the template arguments by value then sometimes reference-types drop their reference-ness along the way.
- My attempted fix was so pass all arguments as non-const reference. This works for most of the cases because constness is preserved in the type itself and arguments that are passed by value are allowed to be converted to reference.
- However, a notable exception is temporary const references. See my edit below for more info.

All this however is only my personal experience. I haven't seen this approach much in other codebases. Because of this I am interested to learn your ideas and insights on above issues.

My main questions are:

- What are the general guidelines and best practices when designing this kind of interface?
- How can I avoid losing type information? (Can it be avoided at all?)
- Can you recommend any good examples of such a design?

#### Update

In response to @Ben Voigt's comment. It seems he on to something. It works with a `const char *` string that is bound to an lvalue, but it doesn't work when passing the result of typeinfo's name() method:

```
template<typename Arg0>
void Create(Arg0 & a) {}

void foo()
{
    // works fine
    const char * typeName = typeid(int).name();
    Create(typeName);

    // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
    // ‘const char*&’ from a temporary of type ‘const char*’
    Create(typeid(int).name());
}
```

Comment: `const` pointers can be passed by reference, I don't know what you did wrong.  Maybe you tried to pass a temporary pointer by non-const reference.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I think you were right. See my edit.

Comment: That's because you can take a `const char(&)[N]` to an N-1 sized string literal- as it is an lvalue. However, you cannot refer to const lvalues or rvalues this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no big deal, really. You pass by reference to `const`, and where a reference to non-`const` is to be passed you require the caller to write [`ref(x)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html). And instead of definining umpteen versions you define a supporting [`ArgPack` template](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/cppx-c98-constructor-arguments-forwarding-v2-posting/) once and for all.

Or, use C++0x purrfect führwarding.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 4):

Not in C++03, buddy. You must explicitly overload for every combination of const reference and non-const reference, which is exponential. In C++0x perfect forwarding and variadic templates will solve this problem.

Comment: Well, he *can* do the silly overloading of combinations, but he doesn't have to. I.e. it's not "must". :-) So that part is sort of -1, but then you mention C++0x stuff which is +1, so, 0 all in all.

Comment: Well, he *does* have to if he wants the interface with the properties he has described.